# I am trying to add a newline in input field by pressing enter key instead of submitting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a newline on pressing enter key, but `\n` is not working here. `\t` is working, as is anything except `\n`.

This code prevents the submitting of the form on pressing the enter key, but doesn't add a newline to the text:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#text').keypress(function(event) {  
     if(event.which == 13) {                    
      event.preventDefault();                   
        var s = $(this).val();              
        $(this).val(s+"\n"); 
     }
  });      
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="text" name="post">
<input type="submit" value="Post">
```

Comment: If you want multiple lines, why not use a textarea

Comment: `input type="text"` doesn't provide you into `newline`. For that you might need to either take help of `textarea` or some `contenteditable div` styled as `input`..

Comment: Pressing enter submits the form by default. You have to use text area instead

Comment: Thanks I get it.

Answer (score 4):

Would it make more sense for you to use a textarea?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

This will prevent submitting the form but also allow you to enter new lines.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't make new lines in an input.
use `<textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>` and change the `rows` value using js.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use  `<textarea rows='20' cols="20"></textarea>`.

Set the values of cols and rows accordingly to your need.

```
<input type="text" name="dmeo">
```

The above line is only useful when we are getting any short data like name, surname, username, etc.

If we are talking about which one is better then we have to be more specific about it application that where we gonna use it. If we are talking about any input field that is used to get data regarding form submission or if we want different types such as submit/radio-button, checkbox or any hidden type then we can use input tag. But if we are talking about accepting any detailed information(address, description of an product, etc..) from the user then textarea is much more preferable. We can also predefine numbers of rows and cols attributes, or even better; through CSS' height and width properties

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow. Could you please add some explanation about why it is better to use `textarea`?

Comment: Well to tell which one is better we have to be more specific about it application that where we gonna use it. If we are talking about any input field that is used to get data regarding form submission or if we want different types such as submit/radio-button,  checkbox or any hidden type then we can use input tag. But if we are talking about accepting any detailed information(address, description of an product, etc..) from the user then textarea is much more preferable. We can also predefine  numbers of rows and cols  attributes, or even better; through CSS' height and width properties.

Comment: thanks. I meant, in general, as a tip for answering questions on Stack Overflow in a way to receive lots of votes, please edit and update your answer with the above information.

Answer (score 0):

To disable form submit on enter btn

```
$("#regForm").keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

but the code above will disable enter btn on the entire form field use this on textarea for new line

```
$('#text').keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var s = $(this).val();
                $(this).val(s + "\n");
            }
        });
```